# How do I pass an array of integers to a Postgres stored procedure with pqxx?

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

Say I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(ids integer[]) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
END;
$$;
```

In pqxx, what is the best way to go about invoking this?  I can invoke integers and strings fine but what is the right type to pass for arrays?

```
conn.prepare("foo_call", "select foo($1)");

conn.prepared("foo_call")(VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently pqxx will play nice with the array being encoded as a string.  I'm  not sure where the syntax for this is defined but it's:

```
'{1, 22, 333}'

typedef list<db_id_t> db_ids_t;

string to_param_string(const db_ids_t& ids) {
    stringstream ss;

    bool first(true);
    for(db_ids_t::const_iterator i=ids.begin();i != ids.end();i++) {
        ss << (first ? "{" : ",") << (*i);
        first = false;
    }

    ss << "}";

    return ss.str();
}
```

If anyone can post an example of not having to encode it as a string I'd be happy to accept that as the answer instead.